# How to insert an image that also acts as a link

Tags: graphics, hyperref

Can an image be included in TeX so that the resulting PDF is clickable leading to a reference?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Just wrap the image in `\href` [1]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\href{http://www.google.de}{\includegraphics{image}}% [1]

\begin{figure}%[2]
    \centering
    \href{http://www.google.de}{\includegraphics{image}}
    \caption{Non linked caption.}
\end{figure}

%\begin{figure}%[3]
%   \centering
%   \href{http://www.google.de}{%
%       \includegraphics{image}
%       \caption{Linked captions won’t work.}
%   }
%\end{figure}

\begin{figure}%[4]
    \centering
    \href{http://www.google.de}{\includegraphics{image}}
    \caption{\href{http://www.google.de}{Workaround for linked captions}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}%[5]
    \href{http://www.google.de}{%
        \parbox{\textwidth}{
            \centering
            \includegraphics{image}
            \caption{Linked captions won’t work.}
        }
    }
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}%[6]
    \centering
    \href{http://www.google.de}{%
        \scalebox{0.5}{
            \parbox{\textwidth}{
                \centering
                \textbf{A Title}\\
                \includegraphics{image}}
        }
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

To add a caption just use the `{figure}` environment as usual and put in the linked graphic [2]: Wrapping the caption in `\href` too causes an error, since the out will contain paragraphs that can’t be part of a link [3], so you’ll have to link the caption too [4] or you must put the whole `{figure}` content in a `\parbox`, which can be linked [5]. [6] shows hoe to add a title (not caption) and scale text an image with `\scalebox`.

Comment: Nice update, but I have the feeling the OP talks about some sub-title below the image, not a real `\caption`. But I could be wrong of course.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: We all can only guess what the OP want’s, but likely you’re right :-) I added this a possible code for this …

Answer (score 20):

Of course:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% demo option just for the example
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{http://www.tex.stackexchange.com}{\includegraphics{name}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I use `\href{https://gitlab.com/u/SomeName}{\includegraphics[width=0.31cm,height=0.31cm,keepaspectratio]{figures/gitlab_greyscale}}`, but it does not work. Compiling a memoir based document with XeLaTeX. Are there any restrictions (wrt XeLaTeX)?

Comment: I found "my" answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85103/8272

Answer (score 13):

Sure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,graphicx}
\begin{document}

\href{http://www.dante.de}{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{tiger}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does the syntax allow for a title or caption, and would it scale with the picture? How would you give the coordinates for the picture?

Comment: You shouldn't put a float like figure in the argument. But I don't see any reason why boxes like `\parbox` or `tabular` with various content shouldn't work. If you want to scale a text, use `\resizebox` from the graphics package.

Comment: @Maesumi: You should always state such requirements with your question. Are you talking about a normal LaTeX `figure` numbered caption or just some text above or below?

Comment: @Maesumi: I added some possible ways to my answer whowing how to add a caption an link it.

Comment: With thanks to Tobi, Gonzola, Ulrike, Martin. I want a regular picture (not LaTeX generated) with some text that will be either above or below it. It does not have to be a formal caption or title for the picture, just so long as it centers with the picture.

Answer (score 0):

I used a single command with orcid logo picture downloaded from google:

```
\href{https://orcid.org/0000-0001-9743-2851
}{\includegraphics[width=0.15in,height=0.15in]{orcid.jpg}}
```

Following is the picture I used

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. This question was posted seven yers ago and your answer adds nothing to the already existing answers.