# \href and \includegraphics not making hyperlinks in XeLaTeX

Tags: graphics, xetex, hyperref

I need to make hyperlink on a image. For that, I setup as follows.

```
\href{http://stackexchange.com/users/1170155/thekojueffect?tab=accounts}{\includegraphics[height=11pt]{stackexchange.png}}
```

The graphics is shown but the hyperlink is not created.

But when I add text like

```
\href{http://stackexchange.com/users/1170155/thekojueffect?tab=accounts}{\includegraphics[height=11pt]{stackexchange.png}~StackExchange}
```

The hyperlink is created on the text "StackExchange" but I don't want to have text.

How can I create hyperlink on a graphics?

Any hacks/ideas?

I'm using Ubuntu and `xelatex -version` gives

```
XeTeX 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.0
Copyright 2012 SIL International and Jonathan Kew.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 49.1 [with modifications for XeTeX]
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.7; using 1.2.7
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.4.10; using 2.4.11
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.10.1; using 2.10.2
Compiled with libpng version 1.2.49; using 1.2.49
Compiled with poppler version 0.20.5
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I do get a hyperlink with the first example code; if I click on the image I go to your SE account page.

Comment: @egreg Uff, I've tried alot with that but no hyperlink. Anyway, will try again. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @egreg I'm not getting hyperlink. I'm using `evince` in Ubuntu. What do you use?

Comment: Try opening the PDF with another viewer. I'm on Mac OS X; I'll try also with Ubuntu in a few minutes.

Comment: I tried on a Xubuntu machine running 13.04, Evince 3.6.1 and TeX Live 2013; the link is there.

Comment: @egreg Thanks again but mine isn't working.

Comment: Can you add some details about your OS and TeX distribution?

Comment: @egreg Updated my question. Since I'm using `fontspec` package, I'm required to use `Xelatex`.

Comment: Yes, with `xelatex` the link is missing. But the issue is already covered here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84921/href-not-working-with-image-but-ok-with-text

Comment: @egreg Happy that it's not just the problem with mine latex. Any idea about that?

Comment: Did you see the link I added?

Comment: @egreg I tried using `hyperref` package earlier, but it gave some errors which I'll have to figure out.