# How to insert a linkedin logo to my document that also acts as a link to my profile

Tags: hyperref, links, cv, logos

I would like to insert a linkedin logo to my document that also acts as a link to my profile.

Here's my code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{25mm} 
    \includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.5in,clip,keepaspectratio]{AuthorImage}
\end{wrapfigure}\par
\textbf{Author A} \lipsum[1]  

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \href{http://www.google.de}{%
        \scalebox{0.1}{
            \parbox{\textwidth}{
                \centering
                \includegraphics{LinkedinImage}}
        }
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to inert LinkedIn logo just after **Author A** or at the end of the paragraph.

Thanks

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54927/how-to-insert-an-image-that-also-acts-as-a-link

Comment: Please show what you've tried already and where you have your difficulties

Comment: Welcome on TeX.SE! You can use `hyperref` and `fontawe­some`-packages, and creating an `\href{http://your-lnkdIn-url}{\faLinkedin}` (or `\faLinkedinSquare`). But I would suggest you to have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. `(:`

Answer (score 0):

If you fiddle with this [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), you should be able to solve your problem. Of course, you can adapt [the icon](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) and what you put in the hyperlink!

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
    Check-out my profile: \href{https://www.linkedin.com}{\faLinkedinSquare}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Using `fontawesome` icons might be better than embedding an image in this case since it is vectorized and matches you line-height. However, you do not have only two displays.