# Open a PNG externally by clicking on the image, potentially via hyperref

Tags: hyperref, png

**Aim:**

Open a PNG image externally by clicking on its image in a PDF.

**Motivation:**

I would like to have, say, four tiny images on my PDF side by side. If I want to examine one of them, I would like to click on the image, so that it can pop out in a new window for my close inspections.

**Problem:**

We *can open a web-page or an external PDF* by clicking on an image, as exemplified in the following threads:

[How to insert an image that also acts as a link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54927/how-to-insert-an-image-that-also-acts-as-a-link)

[Link to local (PDF) file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46488/link-to-local-pdf-file)

[Does hyperref work between two files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41539/does-hyperref-work-between-two-files)

[Make hyperref links open in new browser window for easier navigation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200577/make-hyperref-links-open-in-new-browser-window-for-easier-navigation)

Could you please tell me if it is possible to open a PNG externally (say in a new window popping out) by modifying one of the above approaches, or with another approach?

**Attempts:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \href{run:./local/path/boat.png}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{boat.png}}
  \caption{A boat.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Yet `Unable to open external link` error is thrown every time even though I have tried various combinations.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct path? The above code works for me if I adjust the file path. If boat.png is in the same directory as article.tex, have you tried \href{run:./boat.png}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{boat.png}} ?

Comment: Wow, it worked! I feel dumb! Please post an answer, so that I can accept it. Many thanks.

Comment: You might want to use `\href[pdfnewwindow]{...}`  It works with Acrobat, but not with every PDF reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have the correct path? The above code works for me if I adjust the file path. If boat.png is in the same directory as article.tex, have you tried 
\href{run:./boat.png}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{boat.png}} ?