# Is it possible to make a presentation that renders LaTeX and includes youtube videos?

Tags: presentations, video

I need to make a presentation which is both formula-heavy and includes several videos. Ideally I would use something like media9 package, but that does not seem to work any more. I am in principle open to using any  presentation tool.

Comment: media9 does not work any more? Can you tell us why? If you need to go to youtube during a presentation, why don't you do so?

Comment: You could manually add a picture and link, see here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54928/90297

Comment: @pluton Unfortunately, embedded YT videos don't work anymore in PDF.  This is because YouTube have abandoned their Flash-based video payer (for obvious reasons) two or three years ago.

Comment: @AlexG I see. It is still possible to extract frames from the video and insert them back into the presentation? On YT, html5 is the format by default?

Comment: @pluton Yes, html5 is the only option. If one chooses SVG as the output format (`latex`+`dvisvgm`) embedding YT videos would be possible.

Comment: @pluton Ideally, I would prefer both not to have heavy video files in my presentation AND not to break the flow of the presentation by switching over to browser and then switching back, all while presenting over videoconferencing and sharing screen. Embedded youtube (or some other hosting site?) video seems to fit, except for the html vs flash issue, that AlexG explained, and that as far as I can tell broke media9's ability to do exactly this. Hence this question asking for other options. I'm not even asking it to be a PDF (as I understand PDF does not support html5)...

Comment: @Max It is possible to compile the complete `beamer`-class presentation to SVG *instead* of PDF and show it in Chrome or Firefox. As soon as I have time, I will think about a user command for embedding YT into SVG or extend the `media4svg` package which already provides a user command for embedding MP4, MP3 and other web-compatible media formats.

Comment: @AlexG That would be great.